# Declare a variable across all files in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a set of Python files as follows:

```
py-app/
main.py
module1.py
```

Inside main.py I declare a variable config as follows

`config = {"param1": "value1", "param2":"value2"}`

How can I make `config` variable global in order for it to be accessed in module1.py as follows:

Inside module1.py

```
def foo()
    print(config["param1"])
```

Comment: Don't. That kind of thing causes a lot of problems. Put it in a module for other modules to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this from the official website:

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

What you can do is - create a special module to store all the global variables there and access them by importing the module.

This singleton design pattern is followed and if you modify the state in one file it will be reflected everywhere. It basically works like a session object.

If required, you can initialize the values as well.